# What is this simple football game ("Piłkarzyki na papierze" in Polish) called in English?

Tags: game-identification

I would like to know what is this simple football (soccer) game called in English:

[image]

[image]

Source:

- http://www.kurnik.pl/pilka/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called [Paper Soccer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_Soccer) by Wikipedia, [versions](http://www.kongregate.com/games/k_meleon1982/paper-soccer) can be found online and there seem to be forms of it available on both Google Play and the Apple App Store.

More cultured people might call it Paper Football, but apparently that's [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_football).